# Parsing string outside parenthetical expression

Tags: python, regex

I have the following text:

```
s1 = 'Promo Tier 77 (4.89 USD)'
s2 = 'Promo (11.50 USD) Tier 1 Titles Only'
```

From this I want to pull out the number that is not included in the parenthetical. It would be:

```
s1 --> '77'
s2 --> '1'
```

I am currently using the weak regex `re.findall('\s\d+\s',s1)`. What would be the correct regex? Something like `re.findall('\d+',s1)` but excluding anything within the parenthetical.

```
>>> re.findall('\d+',s1)
['77', '4', '89'] # two of these numbers are within the parenthetical. 
                  # I only want '77'
```

Comment: Will there be more than one number outside parenthesis ? what about the numbers that are inside parenthesis ? will they always follow the same format.number followed by USD ?

Comment: I'm not sure about the numbers within the parenthesis, but I basically want to ignore everything within the parenthetical. \d+ outside parentheses would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way that I find useful is to use the alternation operator in context placing what you want to exclude on the left side, (**saying** *throw this away, it's garbage*) and place what you want to match in a capturing group on the right side.

Then you can combine this with [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) or use a list comprehension to remove the empty list items that the regular expression engine picks up from the expression on the left side of the alternation operator.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """Promo (11.50 USD) Tier 1 Titles Only
Promo (11.50 USD) (10.50 USD, 11.50 USD) Tier 5
Promo Tier 77 (4.89 USD)"""
>>> filter(None, re.findall(r'\([^)]*\)|(\d+)', s))
['1', '5', '77']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a temporary string that has the parenthesis section removed, then run your code. I used a space so that numbers before and after the missing string section can't be joined.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Promo Tier 77 (11.50 USD) Tier 1 Titles Only'
>>> temp = re.sub(r'\(.*?\)', ' ', s)
Promo Tier 77   Tier 1 Titles Only
>>> re.findall('\d+', temp)
['77', '1']
```

And you could of course shorten this to a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Do some splitting on your strings. eg pseudocode

```
s1 = "Promo Tier 77 (4.89 USD)"
s  = s1.split(")")
for ss in s :
  if "(" in ss: # check for the open brace
     if the number in ss.split("(")[0]:  # split at the open brace and do your regex
        print the number
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(\b\d+\b)(?=(?:[^()]*\([^)]*\))*[^()]*$)
```

Try this.Grab the capture.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/gT6kI4/7